# Get values from inside a nested function using this

Tags: javascript, oop, object, constructor, this

I have a piece of code which has two nested functions inside a main one.

**How do I retrieve the nested functions using `this` keyword? Is it possible?**

I have tried `times().present()` and `new times().present()` , none of them seem to work and return `undefined`.

I have found similar examples on [w3School](https://www.w3schools.com/jS/js_object_prototypes.asp) but cant seem to implement it in this case.

Thanks in advance.

```js
function times() {
  var timingObj = function() {
    this.present = currentTime;
    this.past = pastTime;
  };

  var currentTime = function() {
    var hourMin = new Date().getHours() + ":" + new Date().getMinutes();
    return hourMin;
  };

  var pastTime = function() {
    if (new Date().getDay() == 5) {
      return "07:40"
    } else {
      return "16:30"
    }
  };
  return timingObj;
}

console.log(times().present());
//console.log(new times().present());
```

Comment: Any reason you aren't using `class` for this?

Comment: @BrandonDyer am new to using objects. but I will look up class now

Comment: `new (times())().present()`

Comment: @adiga I knew I was close! thanks :)

Comment: You want to use the `new` operator on the function *returned* by `times`. Not on `times` itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Method `call()`.

```js
function times() {
  var timingObj = function() {
    this.present = currentTime;
    this.past = pastTime;
  };

  var currentTime = function() {
    var hourMin = new Date().getHours() + ":" + new Date().getMinutes();
    return hourMin;
  };

  var pastTime = function() {
    if (new Date().getDay() == 5) {
      return "07:40"
    } else {
      return "16:30"
    }
  };
  return timingObj;
}

times().call(null);
console.log(present(), past());
```

OR define them as `prototype`

```js
function times() {
  var timingObj = function() {
    this.present = timingObj.prototype.currentTime;
    this.past = timingObj.prototype.pastTime;
  };

  timingObj.prototype.currentTime = function() {
    return new Date().getHours() + ":" + new Date().getMinutes();
  };

  timingObj.prototype.pastTime = function() {
    return new Date().getDay() === 5 ? "07:40" : "16:30";
  };

  return timingObj;
}

console.log(times().prototype.currentTime(), times().prototype.pastTime());

//times().call(null);
//console.log(present(), past());
```

Answer (score 3):

```js
function times() {
  var currentTime = function() {
    var hourMin = new Date().getHours() + ":" + new Date().getMinutes();
    return hourMin;
  };

  var pastTime = function() {
    if (new Date().getDay() == 5) {
      return "07:40"
    } else {
      return "16:30"
    }
  };
  
  return {
    present: currentTime,
    past: pastTime
  };
}

console.log(times().present())
```